# JPA / Hibernate - How to EAGERly fetch EmbeddedId?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity(name = "game_users")
public class GameUser {

    private GameUsersPK primaryKey;

    @EmbeddedId
    public GameUsersPK getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }
    ...
}
```

With the following PK:

```
@Embeddable
public class GameUsersPK implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    private Game game;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

When I query for a `GameUser` by executing:

```
GameUser gameUser = em.createQuery("from game_users", GameUser.class).setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
```

I notice Hibernate is executing two queries - one from `game_users` and one from `games left outer join users`.

Can I make Hibernate fetch all entities in one query - `from game_users, games, users`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
select gu from GameUser gu
left join fetch gu.primaryKey.game
left join fetch gu.primaryKey.user
```

Read the [Hibernate documentation about HQL and associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

Comment: Thanks but I know I can explicitly state my other beans. I want to avoid it - can't I annotate EAGER somewhere so this will be done automatically :-)

Comment: Using this query - I see that the select is querying all three tables but the second select is still executed

Comment: It would help if we had the mapping of all three entities, and the query that Hibernate executes and that you want to avoid.